# How can we split the list elements in new lines

Tags: haskell

I am still a beginer in Haskell and I want to know how can I split the numbers in a list in new lines so each line contains one element of the list.

Comment: Give an example of what you have, and what result you want.

Answer (score 5):

If you have a `[Char]`, a String, you may use the function `lines` that splits it... But I think what you're looking for is this:

```
as_lines l = unlines $ map show l
```

`unlines :: [String] -> String` concatenates the given Strings, using a newline as the connector. I hope this does what you want.